# is gramerly correct to say it?

Tags: grammar, tenses

I know that present perfect tense can be use if we talking  about several different actions which have occurred in the past at different times

Is the sentence down below grammatically correct?

> We have always eaten at this table.

Comment: Why do you think your text might *not* be "grammatically correct"? If the answer is just "Gramerly [spellchecker?] doesn't like it", I don't think ELU will be interested.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I am not quite good in understanding of present perfect tense, and I wanna know: am I right  understood  the usage e cases of present perfect tense

Comment: @FumbleFingers so, is my sentence correct?

Comment: Yes, it's fine. But *why* are you asking? Perhaps you think you should use Simple Present *We always eat at this table* - which is also fine, but ***may*** (though not *always*) carry a different nuance.

Comment: As FumbleFingers says, you are not really asking your actual question that you're actually having. We really need to know what you are trying to translate. Is it "мы всегда ели за этим столом", is it "мы всегда едим за этим столом", is it something else entirely, and in what context. Yes, "we have always eaten" is correct; but so is "we always ate", and so is "we always eat". Any dictionary will tell you as much, What it won't tell you is whether you should actually use any of those or not. It won't answer your actual question. We could. If only we knew what that question is.

Comment: @RegDwigнt In Russian the context of my sentence is equal to "мы всегда едим за этим столом"

Comment: @RegDwigнt I’ll  take a note about write a little bit more context for the my future questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's grammatically correct.

From [Grammarly.com](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/present-perfect-tense/),

> You can use the present perfect to talk about the duration of something that started in the past is still happening.

Comment: The url is 'grammarly' with two 'a's

Comment: Ha! Yes... Thanks! Updated... *sheepish* :-)